# System.Private.Uri - System.BadImageFormatException

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.2

I have this application below which already runs in production and yesterday I opened the code again and start running with the error:

```
System.BadImageFormatException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Private.Uri, Version=4.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Format of the executable (.exe) or library (.dll) is invalid.'
```

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Jonav.SmsUI
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
}
```

Anyone has experienced this? how did you solved this?

EDIT: I don't have direct reference to System.Private.Uri

[image]

Comment: Ensure you're using the same .NET Core version and NuGet packages as-in production.

Comment: hi.. I had no changes to the solution since it went to production (of course it's already working), it's just now i have to add something new to the application and had this error.